# Bootstrap Navbar works for some, but not everyone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been having problems with Bootstrap Nav Bar drop downs.  I take the code directly from w3schools, but the drop downs don’t work for everyone.  They work just fine for me and some of my friends but for others it doesn’t work at all.  I've been looking around and people all seem to have there own JavaScript or some side code.  Is this just a unfixable problem with bootstrap?  And if so, is there some way to detect if a user is having the problem?  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Dropdown test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
.SOP {color: #FF0000;font-weight:bold;}
.AOP {color: #0066ff;font-weight:bold;}
.HOP {color: #00ff00;font-weight:bold;}
.VOP {color: #eeee00;font-weight:bold;}
.member {color: #009933;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.php">Dropdown Test</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="main.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="memberslist.php">Members</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Mail
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="sendmail.php">Send Mail</a></li>
            <li><a href="newmail.php">Read New Mail</a></li>
            <li><a href="oldmail.php">Read Old Mail</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Profile
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="disabled"><a href="settings.php">Invite Codes</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      <li class="disabled"><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="container">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum commodo augue iaculis, dictum ante eget, consequat purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum malesuada risus at condimentum condimentum. Sed tempor, elit non sodales commodo, dui elit auctor odio, id sollicitudin nisi nulla et urna. Nullam id rhoncus magna, nec posuere tortor. Duis scelerisque, nunc vel commodo fermentum, urna nunc lobortis diam, nec aliquam sem mi id dui. Morbi vitae leo ac felis congue maximus a in risus. Curabitur vehicula ornare porta. Ut pretium posuere dolor, vel ullamcorper metus gravida vel. Sed commodo justo id tincidunt posuere. Praesent quis aliquam felis. Sed quam ante, vestibulum vitae turpis eleifend, bibendum pretium arcu. Quisque vitae congue tellus, id molestie mi. </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should include all js files in the bottom of the page for faster page load and proper functionality.

Comment: You need to ask your friends if they have console errors. Secondly, remove the `http:` and `https:`, and just make it `//domain.blah.blah......`. This gets rid of SSL issues (and could be a problem that they can't access it). As far as moving it on the bottom of the page, that only somewhat helps load times, not really proper functionality (meaning it'll still work regardless if it's on top or bottom). Also attempt to actually serve up the `.js` and `.css` files from your server, rather than from CDN (could be firewall / download issue).

Comment: I tried that, didn't help

Comment: Can you get the console log from your friends' browser and posted so that your problem is more obvious.